# Issue with getItems() method on one-to-many jpa mapping exposed via REST

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

With the latests versions (1.3.0.M4) of the libs from the title I have the problem with one to many  (`LoggingRequest->LoggingRequestItem`) relationship when the property method is named `getItems()/setItems()`. The `LoggingRequest` holds a one-to-many collection of `LoggingRequestItem`(s).

Both `Repositories` are exposed via rest.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOGGING_REQUESTS")
public class LoggingRequest extends StandardPersistentEntity implements Serializable {
...
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "loggingRequest")
  @JsonProperty(value="items")
  public Collection<LoggingRequestItem> getItems() {
        return items;
  }

  @JsonProperty(value="items")
  public void setItems(Collection<LoggingRequestItem> data) {
        this.items = data;
  }
}
```

When the method name is called `getItems()` the call to http://localhost:8080/loggingRequests returns:

```
{
      "owner" : "test",
      "status" : "NEW",
      "statusChangedAt" : "2015-08-17T15:24:19.975",
      "createdAt" : "2015-08-17T15:24:19.972",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/loggingRequests/11424011293097884",
          "templated" : false
        },
        "loggingRequest" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/loggingRequests/11424011293097884",
          "templated" : false
        },
        "items" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/loggingRequests/11424011293097884/items",
          "templated" : false
        }
      }
```

When the method name is changed to something else like `getLoggingRequestItems()` the returned json is different:

```
{

      "owner" : "test",
      "status" : "NEW",
      "statusChangedAt" : "2015-08-17T15:24:19.975",
      "createdAt" : "2015-08-17T15:24:19.972",
      "items" : [ {
        "variableData" : {
          "variableName" : "BR2.BWS.2L1.H_ROT:I_TOTAL_OUT",
          "datatype" : "NUMERIC",
          "clientLogOnChange" : false,
          "loggingRequired" : true,
          "unit" : "bits",
          "description" : "integral bits profile surface OUT",
          "clientLogFixedRateMs" : 3600,
          "deadtimeIntervalType" : "SECOND",
          "fixedLoggingIntervalType" : "HOUR",
          "clientRoundingCompare" : 2,
          "clientRoundingLog" : null,
          "dvnMaxSize" : 1,
           ...
}
}
```

In principle it looks like the content of the associated collection is dependent on the method name.

What am I missing here? Is it a bug somewhere?

Thanks in advance,
Jakub

Comment: The project is based on spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, hibernate for jpa.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually found an answer: the change of the method on the fly with spring-devtools reload does not always work. When restarting the project I  got exactly the same behavior for both methods (which is a link):

```
 {
          "id" : 6303064632841896,
          ""owner" : "TEST",
      "status" : "NEW",
      "statusChangedAt" : "2015-08-27T16:13:16.436",
      "createdAt" : "2015-08-27T16:13:16.436",
          "_links" : {
            "self" : {
              "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/loggingRequests/6303064632841896",
              "templated" : false
            },
            "loggingRequest" : {
              "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/loggingRequests/6303064632841896",
              "templated" : false
            },
            "loggingRequestItems" : {
              "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/loggingRequests/6303064632841896/loggingRequestItems",
              "templated" : false
            }
          }
        }
```

But when I ask for this LoggingRequest explicitely I get it without the link to the items:

```
{
  "id" : 6303064632841896,
  "owner" : "TEST",
  "status" : "NEW",
  "statusChangedAt" : "2015-08-27T16:13:16.436",
  "createdAt" : "2015-08-27T16:13:16.436",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/loggingRequests/6303064632841896",
      "templated" : false
    },
    "loggingRequest" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/loggingRequests/6303064632841896",
      "templated" : false
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I follow the link I get an empty response (while there are 100 items for this request):

```
curl -i -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json"  http://localhost:8080/api/loggingRequests/6303064632841896/loggingRequestItems
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 28 Aug 2015 13:26:12 GMT

{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/loggingRequests/6303064632841896/loggingRequestItems",
      "templated" : false
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea why is this the case? I've checked the Response object and those items are there but they are not rendered correctly to the output.